# How to find an struct element in a two dimention vector?

Tags: c++, search, vector, stl, find

I have a struct:

```
struct node
{
    string val;
    int count;
};
```

I have defined my vector in this way:

```
typedef std::vector<node> StringVector;
typedef std::vector<StringVector> StringVector2D;
```

And here is my code:

```
string arr[6] = {"hi","mr","ben","ss","rty","ben"};

StringVector2D twoD;    

StringVector inner;
twoD.push_back(inner);  


for(int f=0;f<6;f++)
{

    node tmp;
    tmp.val = arr[f];
    tmp.count = arr[f].size();

    twoD[0].push_back(tmp); 

}


for (StringVector::iterator it = twoD[0].begin() ; it != twoD[0].end(); ++it)
{
    cout<< it->val<<endl;
}
```

... In this example I have only one dimension in my outer vector so as you can see it is: `twoD[0]`

```
StringVector::iterator it = find(twoD[0].begin(), twoD[0].end(), "ben");

if(it == twoD[0].end())
{
    cout<<"not found"<<endl;
}
```

I used this

```
StringVector::iterator it = find(twoD[0].begin().val, twoD[0].end().val, "ben");
```

and

```
StringVector::iterator it = find(twoD[0].begin()->val, twoD[0].end()->val, "ben");
```

But it did not work. Appreciate any suggestion.

**EDIT**

I have defined my own search:

```
  struct find_word
    {
        string val;
        find_word(string val) : val(val) {}
        bool operator () ( const find_word& m ) const
        {
            return m.val == val;
        }
};
```

And call it here:

```
StringVector::iterator it = find_if(twoD[0].begin()->val, twoD[0].end()->val, find_word("ben"));
```

But can't make it work.

Comment: Elements of `twoD[0]` are `node`s. You are searching for a string. What does it mean for a `node` to match a string? How is the compiler supposed to know that?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That's my question. In this case what should we do?

Comment: Why do you want a comparator that takes itself as a parameter? You want to compare a string to a `node`, no?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik There was a typing error I fixed it. Yes I am looking for comparing a string with val inside the node.

Comment: `find_word::operator()` still takes `const find_word&` as a parameter, and doesn't mention `node` in any way.

Comment: asked and answered only last week, so a dupe. I need to find the other question though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the comparer functor of the `find_if`.

```
struct find_word {
    string val;
    find_word(string val) 
      : val(val) {}
    bool operator()(const node& m) const { return m.val == val; }
}; //                     ^^^^ the change is here
```

And use the `find_if` version like this:

```
StringVector::iterator it = find_if(twoD[0].begin(), twoD[0].end(), find_word("ben"));
//                              the change is here ^     and here ^
```

The comparer functor of the `find_if` receive as parameter in the `operator()` an element of the container to find in. In this case `twoD[0].begin()` and `twoD[0].end()` give you access to the elements of the inner vector and the parameters receive is the type of the element storage in the inner vector `node`.